# Generating a UTF-8 file from a jar-File

Tags: java, file, utf-8, character-encoding, jar

I want to create a UTF-8 file from a jar-file with the following code:

```
public class UTF8 {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
    "utf8.txt"), "UTF8"));
  out.write("Look at this BASTÖÖÜÜÄÄ!");
 }
}
```

This code works very well using eclipse. But if I pack it to a jar file, it uses a platform depended file encoding (Cp1252 for example on Windows). What could I do against that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `"UTF8"` should be `"UTF-8"`.
2. Also [`OutputStreamReader(outputStream, encosingString)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) throws `UnsupportedEncodingException` which you should catch.
3. Major mistake: never catch (or pass to main) a generic `Exception`

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {}
   ```

   This prevented you to see what your real exception was and where happened.

Comment: Having "throws Exception" in the main method is perfectly OK - the exception will print its stack trace to stderr and the JVM will end.

Comment: I used "throws Exception" just for the test program to keep it small and simple. Also "UTF8" and "UTF-8" behaves on the same way.

Comment: I found the Problem: I used http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ to start the jar on Windows, which changes the behavior. Now I use a bat-file and everything is ok :)

Comment: Huh?? Are you saying that `OutputStreamReader(out, "UTF-8")` did not do UTF-8 encoding if you started your app via different launcher? This sounds like a major JVM bug, so I doubt it.

Comment: I don't know what launch4j changes on startup of a jar file. OutputStreamReader(out, "UTF-8") doesn't change the encoding to utf8.

Answer (score 4):

In the JVM options field on the JRE tab in Launch4j (after loading your configuration file) enter the following:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

ALternatively, can specify the same thing in an ini file for your application - see the launch4j documentation at:

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Additional_jvm_options

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb when debugging encoding problems: if you have non-us-ascii letters in string literals, try to replace them by Unicode escapes (i.e. `BAST\u00d6\u00d6\u00dc\u00dc\u00c4\u00c4`). If the problem disappears, you have a source/compiler encoding mismatch.

For example, the behaviour you describe may happen if your source encoding is Windows-1252 whereas compiler encoding is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`"UTF-8"`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem .. and i solved it with 
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar CAP.jar ( where CAP the name of the JAR File)

I mad a batch file. open text file, write the line above and save it as .bat and it should work